# How come PHP cURL can perform a request, but jQuery AJAX doesn't?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, curl

I have setup a simple script that allows for data to be send to my server using AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: method,
    data: data
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Now I have added the following **Access-Control-Allow** rules to my `.htaccess`:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "https://www.randomsite9734784.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "DELETE"
```

This works as expected: whenever I send an AJAX request, I get a message that the origin doesn't match, bla bla bla, end of story. Perfect.

Now, when I use my cURL function in PHP, I managed to perform all kinds of requests. I would have expected this to have the same response, but somehow it bypasses the .htaccess file, of some sort.

I would really like to know why this happens and how I can protect myself against both of these request methods.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

FYI, this is my current .htacess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://somerandomdomain.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "DELETE"
```

Now, to be clear: all I want to know is how I can make sure that (in this case) ONLY the delete request may be performed from somerandomdomain.com, instead of all kinds of requests from all kinds of locations...

:-) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery / JavaScript is doing in the client side, where browsers apply the restriction of Cross-Origin Request Sharing.

The server doesn't have any restrictions, as far as PHP can use a lot of things like URL with `fopen()`, etc.

The main reason for this restriction is, JavaScript can be executed by anyone in the client side, while the server side code can be executed only by the people who have the access to server side scripts. When a novice user is given a URL to be executed, (AJAX Request), it gets executed on the client where the URL is fired.

This opens up the issues like access to the cookies on the domain, session details, etc. So, for example, when you have an API that can send email using GMail, and you go into a malicious website, there could be a JavaScript, that could fire an AJAX request to say:

```
POST https://mail.google.com/api/mail/send
```

With some details, and this gets executed without your knowledge, but with your logged in credentials. This cannot be done using the server side script, because there's nothing like an open session or the flow is controlled.

> I would have expected this to have the same response, but somehow it bypasses the .htaccess file, of some sort.

Your `.htaccess` is weak enough to requests to sneak in. So you need to correct your `.htaccess` file. You may post the source of your `.htaccess` file so we can advice you on that as well.

I hope this answered your question.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I was wondering though, even if this security is in place client-side wise, what prevents attackers from using the same technique on the server-side instead?

Comment: @Mark As I said you, in the server side you aren't logged in. The client side restrictions are added by Browsers and it is a Standard.

Comment: I noticed your htaccess remark; Currently, the htaccess only consists of those rules, including: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]` -- How would you recommend protecting myself to exclude the mentioned requests via back-end?

Comment: @Mark Kindly edit your question and paste. Every space and line endings are important. I hope you understand. Comments are just for comments. :) You can edit your question by clicking on the edit button below it.

Comment: @Mark I'll be offline for an hour. `:(` If you like my answer you may accept. I will definitely answer, once I am back.

Comment: You can also enable the use of AJAX request on cross domain by going through http://enable-cors.org for more information.

Comment: did you happen to come up with anything in the meantime? I appreciate it.

Comment: @Mark Nothing as of now, buddy. :( This is what I came upto.

Comment: Ok, that's too bad. I thought perhaps you had a copy-ready example of an htaccess that is strong enough to prevent requests sneak in... Thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 0):

For your case: If you can use CURL , use CURL but if you really want use ajax,  you need to add CORS access on client side AND server side (this is the case that you build your own API) if you use extern API well know, they should have add a topic about CORS issue which explain which headers you have to add to your request to make it work. I hope you understand what i'm saying

Comment: I don't want to use AJAX at all, but it shows how my request limitations are only respected when using AJAX, not when using PHP cURL. :-)